# (Beginner) Using 2 loops to determine if number is prime...doesn't work for some numbers

Tags: loops, input, while-loop, division, do-while

I'm just gonna post the functional part of my program here (not the methods for the hello and goodbye graphics...they're fine!). Basically the program has the user input a whole number, determines if it's prime or not, and asks them if they want to do it again. It continues to run the loop until they say no.

Here's what I have so far.
Main:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int n = 0, even = 2;
    int answer = 0;
    String reply;
    char doAgain = 'Y';

    Welcome();

    do
    {
    System.out.print("Enter a whole number: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    PrimeTest(n);

    System.out.print("Try another number? (Y/N): ");
    reply = scan.next().toUpperCase();
    doAgain = reply.charAt(0);
    System.out.println();

    }while(doAgain != 'N');

    Goodbye();
}
```

And here's the part that isn't working, apparently--it does nothing for 3, and says 21 IS a prime number:

```
public static void PrimeTest(int n)
{
    int two = 2;

    while(two <= n / 2)
    {
        if(n % two == 0)
            {
            System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number.");
            System.out.println();
            }
        else
            {
            System.out.println(n + " is a prime number.");
            System.out.println();
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Whether it's efficiency, or just pointing out where I messed up. Please let me know what other details you need to help me.

Comment: 21 *isn't* a prime number.  7*3

Comment: I don't see how that PrimeTest method works at all.  You never change `n` or `two` in the loop, so the most likely result is either an endless loop, or nothing happens at all.

Comment: Robert Harvey - I meant to say it says it IS a prime number...

Answer (score 0):

That test is as faulty as it can be... it simply checks if a number is even (but you've substituted words for saying it is/isn't a prime).

You also never change `two`, so technically that `while` loop should never end.

> it does nothing for 3

`two <= n / 2` will always evaluate to false when `n` is equal to three - so nothing will get printed because the `while` loop won't get entered.

> and says 21 IS a prime number

What your modulus calculation is doing is showing that 21 is *odd*, but because you've changed the wording it shows as *prime*.

Comment: @Mazzone The increment needs to be *inside* the loop - otherwise how will it ever exit once you're in there?